# Range piped to Enum.into throws warning

Tags: elixir

I have a range that I am piping to `Enum.into ([])` which throws a warning.  What's wrong here?

```
iex(1)> 1..5 |> Enum.into ([]) 
warning: you are piping into a function call without parentheses...
```

After adding parentheses

```
iex(2)> (1..5) |> Enum.into ([])
warning: you are piping into a function call without parentheses...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the space around the argument to `Enum.into`. It's not interpreted as parenthesis for the function call, but rather as a grouping mechanism around one of the arguments. Space is not allowed between function name and arguments.

`1..5 |> Enum.into ([])` is the same as `1..5 |> Enum.into(([]))` (if we fill the missing parenthesis compiler is complaining about). What you wanted is probably `1..5 |> Enum.into([])`, which is a correct call, that the compiler does not complain about.

Comment: Any idea why `Enumerable not implemented for 90` is thrown when using single element. e.g. `90 |> Enum.into([])`

Comment: It's equivalent to calling `Enum.into(90, [])`. First argument to most functions from `Enum`, must implement the `Enumerable` protocol. Integers do not implement it - enumerable is about values that are composed from multiple other values. Integers are just a single value, it doesn't really make sense to implement `Enumerable` for them.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the warning, put your parentheses around the whole `Enum.into` shebang:

```
(1..5) |> (Enum.into [] )
```

I'm not 100% sure why Elixir complains here; the warning mentions

```
 foo 1 |> bar 2 |> baz 3
```

should be rewritten as

```
 foo(1) |> bar(2) |> baz(3)
```

which - to my understanding - is exactly what you did. Probably related to the partial application of `Enum.into` to `[]`.

Comment: The issue (as Michal Muskala points out) is the space between the function name and the argument.